# How to re-define indexes in a postgres SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table which is automatically created in my DB.
This is the description of the table using the `\d` command.

Table "public.tableA":

```
    Column  | Type      | Modifiers                      
    ----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------
     var_a  | integer   | not null
     var_b  | integer   | not null
     var_c  | bigint    | not null default nextval('var_c_sequence'::regclass)
     var_d  | integer   | 
     var_e  | integer   | 
     var_f  | smallint  | default mysessionid()
     var_g  | smallint  | default (-1)
     var_h  | boolean   | default false
     var_g  | uuid      |
```

Indexes:

```
        "tableA_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (var_c)
        "tableA_edit" btree (var_g) WHERE var_g <> (-1)
        "tableA_idx" btree (var_a)
```

Check constraints:

```
        "constraintC" CHECK (var_f > 0 AND var_d IS NULL AND var_e IS NULL OR (var_f = 0 OR var_f = (-1)) AND var_d IS NOT NULL AND var_e IS NOT NULL)
```

Triggers:

```
        object_create BEFORE INSERT ON tableA FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_tableA()
        object_update BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON tableA FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_tableA()
```

I'm interested in creating this table myself, and I'm not quite sure on how to define this indices manually, any ideas?

Comment: You should show some code you're working on. And users will try to improve it and find a solution for your issues.

Comment: Try running [`pg_dump -s`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) over your database?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've totally missed the boat:

```
alter table public."tableA"
    add constraint "tableA_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (var_c);

create index "tableA_edit" on public."tableA" (var_g) WHERE var_g <> (-1);
create index "tableA_idx" on public."tableA" (var_a);
```

Btree is default, so I don't bother specifying that, but you can if you want.

You didn't ask, but the check constraint syntax is:

```
alter table public."tableA"
    add constraint "constraintC"
    CHECK (var_f > 0 AND var_d IS NULL AND var_e IS NULL OR 
    (var_f = 0 OR var_f = (-1)) AND var_d IS NOT NULL AND var_e IS NOT NULL)
```

By the way, the cheat would be to just look at the DDL in PgAdmin.

All that said, I generally discourage the use of the "quoteS" around a table to enforce upper/lowercase.  There are cases where it makes sense (otherwise, why would the functionality exist), but in many cases it creates so much extra work in the future.  In the case of the index names, it doesn't even buy you anything, since you don't really refer to them in any SQL.